# Twitter data scraping failing unexpectedly - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use [Tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.8.0/api.html) to create a feature vector for a machine learning model.

I am first trying to save all of my followers to a list that I can reference later to collect metadata about them. I have the code below which I have adapted from a few examples:

```
import tweepy
import time

#insert your Twitter keys here
consumer_key =''
consumer_secret=''
access_token=''
access_token_secret=''
twitter_handle='TimBarbalace'

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

users = []

if(api.verify_credentials):
    print("We successfully logged in")

user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_handle).items()

while True:
    try:
        u = next(user)
        users.append(u)

    except:
        time.sleep(2*60)
        print("We got a timeout ... Sleeping for 2 minutes")
        u = next(user)
        users.append(u)
```

This code begins to work (when I added print statements, I could see some Twitter handles being added), but eventually freezes. I let it sit for about 15 minutes, and I cannot get any further. I eventually have to `Ctrl + C` my application and I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WiP2.py", line 25, in <module>
    u = next(user)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 47, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 195, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 73, in next
    **self.kargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 162, in execute
    time.sleep(sleep_time + 5)  # sleep for few extra sec
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am not sure what this error means, or why I cannot collect all of my followers into a list. How can I enter my account information and move all of my followers into a list?

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666135/parsing-json-object-into-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment103695477_58666135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codeblock, taken from the question in the comments, achieves this:

```
import tweepy
import time

#insert your Twitter keys here
consumer_key =''
consumer_secret=''
access_token=''
access_token_secret=''
#twitter_handle='TimBarbalace'

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)

users = []

if(api.verify_credentials):
    print("Logged In Successfully")
else:
    print("Error -- Could not log in with your credentials")

followers = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items()
```